# Enumerated list with headings / titles

Tags: lists, enumitem

I need an enumerated list that has titles like the `description` environment. I'v looked at the `enumitem` package but I'm not sure if / how I can use it for the desired effect. I want the list to look like this:

1. **Apples** 
   Apples are red, and contain iron.
2. **Bananans** 
   Bananas are yellow and contain potassium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a command that acts like `\item[description title]`:

```
\newcommand\descitem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1}\\}
```

You can remove the `\\` if you don’t want a line break. The style of the title is easy to change.

Your `enumerate` environment will look like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \descitem{Apples} Apples are red, and contain iron.
  \descitem{Bananas} Bananas are yellow and contain potassium.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Wow Thanks!I thought I'd need to modify the enumitem templates.